# CSS dont work in jsp

Tags: java, spring, css, jsp

I'm developing my first project and I have problem with css.
I can't move value in jsp file. I have  and want to move it in the middle of the page, but it didn't work. Also sorry about my english if something is unclear to you. I will be very grateful for the help.

header.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

```
<title>${title}</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
```

footer.jsp

```
<footer class="footer">
<div class="container">
    <p><a href="/"> Test Web-Application </a></p>
    <p >&copy 2018 All rights reserved.</p>
</div>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<jsp:include page="tmp/header.jsp"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="page-header">
    <h1 class="title_position">Test project (Overview)</h1>
</div>
<br>
<p class="lead">Test 1: Product <a href="/products">Products</a>and <a href="/users">Users</a>
</p>

<br>
<p class="lead">Test 2: <a href="/users">show Users</a> </p>

<div class="page-header">
    <table id="users">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="disabled-sorting">#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${users}" var="users">
            <tr>
                <td>${user.id}</td>
                <td>${user.username}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<br>
<p class="lead">Test 3: <a href="/categories>">Show categories</a> </p>
<div class="lead">
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="category">
        <tr>
            <td>${category.id}</td>
            <td>${category.categoryOfProduct}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">This button do nothing</button>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
```

style.css

```
html {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;  }


body {
margin-bottom: 60px;}
.footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
height: 60px;
background-color: #f5f5f5;}

.custom-container {
width: auto;
max-width: 680px;
padding: 0 15px;}

.custom-container .text-muted {
margin: 20px 0;}

.title_position {
text-align: center;
font-size: xx-large;}
.menu-size{
font-size: 20px;}

.registrationForm{
background: lime;
text-align: center;}

.production_Page{
margin-left: 500px;}

.indexPage{
margin-left: 500px;}
```

Comment: Don't link to code. Insert the *relevant* code into the question, correctly formatted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) , make your question [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for coding question which have to can be reproduced to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css">
```

use this in header.jsp

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/Web-content/"></mvc:resources>
```

this line in dispatcher-servlet.xml

this maps your Web-content folder with "resources" word (without quotes) .That's why resources is used in above link tag to connect with Web-content folder.

Make sure your directory structure for css files look like webapp/Web-content/css/style.css to use above link tag.

PS: This is my first answer on stack overflow. So, apologies for any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using JSPs I presume you're using a framework such as Spring. I've had some experience in developing Gradle Spring MVC applications, so if this is the case I may be able to help.

Firstly have you tried using the style tag in your html form to check if it's due to having an external css? This would be an indicator in whether you haven't set up the pathway for your project to find the css.

If this is the case that it works internally (in the style tag), you may need to configure the css in an application file. For example, with Gradle I link my external files in an application.properties file.

This is an example:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/WEB-INF/resources/*
```

There are many tutorials online about setting up external files such as CSS and JavaScript. Like I stated previously, if it works internally then it's due to the JSP not being able to find the external CSS file.